# Laravel Search Functionality - Reference Second Model/Collection/Table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement search functionality within my blade for my Script model. It performs fine for everything related to searching directly within the Script collection/table. However, my users also will need to be able to enter in a Patient `first_name` or `last_name` and search for the script records within the Script table that belong to the Patient being searched for. These are connected with a hasMany/belongsTo relationship. Can someone assist me in figuring out how to reference a parent table to display current table results?

**Models**

```
Patient hasMany Script
Script belongsTo Patient          (patient_id)
```

**Script Blade**

```
{{ Form::text('search', $search, ['class' => 'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Search Scripts...']) }}
{{Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'])}}
```

**ScriptController**

```
$search = $request->search;
$patients = Patient::all();
$scripts = Script::
    when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query
                ->where('prescribe_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('efax_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('efax_confirmation', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        })
        ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear. Are you trying to show the patient name and lastname that  the scripts found belong to? Or are you trying to show the scripts that belong to the patient found?

Comment: @danboh I am trying to show the scripts that belong to the patient found.

Answer (score 0):

This is high level, but you could iterate through the found patient's script, assuming that you have a blade where you'd be handling the response:

```
$patient = Patient::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->first();

return view('patient')->with(compact('patient'));
```

Then in the blade, go through the response:

```
@foreach ($patient->scripts as $script)
    {{ $script->name }}
@endforeach
```

Or if you're returning multiple patients then you could do:

```
@foreach ($patients as $patient)
    {{ $patient->name }}
    @foreach ($patient->scripts as $script)
        {{ $script->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Leorent look at the comment above: "I am trying to show the scripts that belong to the patient found"

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to eagerload `Patient` model in search with an `orWhereHas` like below:

```
$scripts = Script::
    when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query
            ->where('prescribe_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('efax_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('efax_confirmation', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
})
    ->orWhereHas('patients', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: I am getting the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'scripts.patients_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `scripts` where exists (select * from `patients` where `scripts`.`patients_id` = `patients`.`id` and (`first_name` like %% or `last_name` like %%)))` from that. When I try changing 'patients' to 'patient', it gives the error `Call to undefined method App\Script::patient()`. the column in scripts that links to patient is `patient_id`